# Facebook OAuthException : Malformed Access Token ErrorCode 190

Tags: java, android, facebook, oauth

I have been battling this problem for hours now and I seem to get nowhere with it. So, I have successfully asked the users to login using Facebook to my android app.

Once they are logged in, I get the access token (a string value) and then use it to make a Request to Facebook to fetch a Page's Posts. Here is how I do that whole process.

```
public void setupFacebook()
{
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session mSession, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


            if (mSession.isOpened() && mSession != null)
            {
                facebookAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();

                Log.d("ACCESSTOKEN", facebookAccessToken);

                fetchPagePosts(facebookAccessToken, mSession);
            }
        }
    });
}

 public  void fetchPagePosts(String token, Session session)
{
    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", "ERROR"+response.getError());
            Log.d("RESPONSE", ""+response);
        }
    };

    String endpoint = String.format("https://graph.facebook.com/"+pageId+"/posts?access_token=%s", facebookAccessToken);

    Log.d("ENDPOINT", endpoint);

    Request request = new Request(session, endpoint,  null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```

The interesting part here is that when I copy the url from my Logcat (what I called endpoint) and paste to my browser, it works perfectly fine.

When I run my code on my tablet though, it returns the **ErrorCode 190** and **HttpStatus 400**.

According to Facebook's documentation, it could be one of several things;

1. Access token is invalid
2. It is expired
3. The user has changed their password or
4. The user has logged out of their account
5. The user has revoked access to their account by your app!

I am stuck here because I have tested the same URL on the browser and it returns the json data I need. It just fails when am running it in android code.

If anyone has suggestions, please help me - will be truly thankful for your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Simple Facebook Android library instead of the Facebook SDK https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook, its a lot simpler.